# Is there a way to convert a unit into another using CSS?

Tags: css, css-calc

Is there a way to convert a unit into another without using JavaScript?

I thought when I divide a `<length>` with another `<length>` unit, the result would be `<number>`. Such as `calc(200px / 100px)` would be `2` so `calc((200px / 100px) * 15deg)` would resolve into `30deg`. But it seems it doesn't work this way.

---

I'm trying to make an element rotate based on the width of the window. When the window is `100px` wide, the element should rotate `15deg`, and `200px` is `30deg` and so on:

```css
transform: rotate(calc((100vw / 100px) * 15deg));
```

Any way to make this work?

```css
.cube {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: salmon;
  
  /* doesn't work */
  transform: rotate(calc((100vw / 100px) * 15deg));
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">Cube</div>
```

Comment: _"But it seems it doesn't work this way."_ - https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-calc-in-css/#aa-division-requires-the-second-number-to-be-unitless: _"Division (/) requires the second number to be unitless"_

Comment: This is just sad :( I guess CSS does have its limitations, although the way I was expecting how it should work makes perfect sense to me

Comment: your code will work fine in probably one or two years, the New spec already defined unit division